# What is the distinction between bias in prediction and parameter estimation?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, bias, unbiased-estimator, estimators

I am trying to understand the distinction between bias in prediction and parameter estimation. This example in Gelman, *Bayesian Data Analysis*, 2nd ed. 2004 pp. 255-256 is very confusing to me.

[image: Gelman 2004 pp. 255-256 example]

1. Why do you get the estimate $\hat{y} = 160 + 0.25(\theta - 160)$ given fixed $\theta$ and $\hat{\theta} = 160 + 2(y - 160)$ under repeated sampling of $y$ conditional on $\theta$? I'm not sure where these equations are coming from.
2. Does the problem here stem from the fact that the distribution is bivariate (normal) rather than $y$ having a distribution based on each $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Conditional on $\theta$, the distribution of $y$ is normal with mean $160 + 0.5 (\theta - 160)$. For each realization $y'$ from this conditional distribution, the posterior mean of $\theta$ is
   $$
   \hat\theta(y') = 160 + 0.5 (y' - 160).
   $$ So the expected value of  $\hat\theta(y')$ conditional on $\theta$ is
   $$
   160 + 0.5 [160 + 0.5 (\theta - 160) - 160] = 160 + 0.25 (\theta - 160).
   $$
2. The bivariate distribution is introduced into the example so that one can talk about "...under repeated sampling of $y$ conditional on $θ$...", i.e. from the conditional distribution of $y$ on $\theta$.

In any case, it seems very Bayesian, and a bit strange from the frequentist perspective, to speak of "...under repeated sampling of $y$ conditional on $θ$...", where $\theta$ is the variable one is trying to predict.

(For a frequentist, unbiased prediction means the mean of the predicted value $\hat{\theta}$ equals the mean of the variable $\theta$ conditional on the predictor, $E[\theta|y]$.)